# Find rank of one column value among other column values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with the format below,

```
ID   Mark1  Mark2  Mark3   Rank_of_Mark1
1     85     80     77          1
1     65     80     70          3
```

I want to get the RANK of Mark1 Amongst the other Marks for a tall list using SQL Server

Thanks

Comment: This is your 4th question. Other formatted your previous ones. Why didn't you learn to do it yourself by now? There is a post preview you can look at before posting.

Answer (score 1):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(ID INT, Mark1 INT, Mark2 INT, Mark3 INT)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(1, 85, 80, 77),          
(1, 65, 80, 70)
```

### Query

```
SELECT *
      ,1 + CASE WHEN Mark1 < Mark2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
         + CASE WHEN Mark1 < Mark3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        AS [Rank_of_Mark1] 
FROM @TABLE
```

*suggested by KingKing*

### Result

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════════════╗
║ ID ║ Mark1 ║ Mark2 ║ Mark3 ║ Rank_of_Mark1 ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════════════╣
║  1 ║    85 ║    80 ║    77 ║             1 ║
║  1 ║    65 ║    80 ║    70 ║             3 ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════════════╝
```

**Important Note**

My solution doesnt handle a situation where two column values are equal, You can replace the `>` or `<` operators with `>=` or `<=` as as required.

Comment: the `CASE WHEN` clause can be simpler if you use some kind of addition operation like in this demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7f446/9

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this is just a sample, there are actually several comlumns to compare with and there are million rows.