# Find rank of column relative to other rows

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alice': [4,15,2], 'Bob': [9,3,5], 'Emma': [4,7,19]})
```

I can find who got the highest score in each round with

```
df.idxmax(1)
> 0      Bob
  1    Alice
  2     Emma
 dtype: object
```

But I would like to find **in which place Bob finished** in each round. Output should be:

```
> 0
  2
  1
```

Seems like something with `argsort` should work, but can't quite get it.

([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352163/find-rank-of-one-column-value-among-other-column-values) is the same question, but in SQL Server.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html):

```
df.rank(axis=1, method='first', ascending=False)
```

*NB. check the methods to find the one that  better suits your need:*

> How to rank the group of records that have the same value (i.e. ties):
>
> average: average rank of the group
> min: lowest rank in the group
> max: highest rank in the group
> first: ranks assigned in order they appear in the array
> dense: like ‘min’, but rank always increases by 1 between groups.

output:

```
   Alice  Bob  Emma
0    2.0  1.0   3.0
1    1.0  3.0   2.0
2    3.0  2.0   1.0
```

*NB. note that the ranks start as 1, you can add `sub(1)` to get a rank from 0*

```
df.rank(axis=1, method='first', ascending=False).sub(1).convert_dtypes()
```

output:

```
   Alice  Bob  Emma
0      1    0     2
1      0    2     1
2      2    1     0
```

Comment: Note: if you want to set the tie (like Alice and Emma in the first row) as equal values, you can use either the `min` or `max` method. For min, both of them will be considered as 2nd position.

Comment: @Cainã I was just wondering if I should add this ;)